Maximum number of black cells in a table where each cell has at most two adjacent black cells: Generalizations of JBMO 2019 P4
The original problem from the 2019 Junior Balkan Mathematical Olympiad goes as follows:
In a $5 \times 100$ table we have coloured black $n$ of its cells. Each of the $500$ cells has at
most two adjacent (by side) cells coloured black. Find the largest possible value of $n$.
The largest $n$ is in fact $302$ which can be proven by summing the number of adjacent cells to all cells in the second and the fourth row. This sum cannot exceed $400$. On the other hand, at most $204$ black cells have been counted once (all cells in the first and fifth row and the $4$ edge cells in the second and fourth row,) and at most $296$ cells twice. Let $a$ be the number of cells coloured black which we counted once, and $b$ be the number of cells colored black which we counted twice. From $$a+2b\le 400, a\le 204\implies a+b\le302.$$ A straightforward construction finishes the proof.

My question is:

Problem 1: In an $m\times n$ table, what is the largest number of black cells if each cell has at most two adjacent black cells?

A related question I have is

Problem 2: In an $m\times n$ table, what is the largest number of black cells if each black cell has at most two adjacent black cells?

The answer to both these questions seems to be the same for the $5\times 100$ case, but I've struggled to prove this. For other cases, they seem to be different.
I've managed to find the largest numbers of black cells for the cases for small $m$, but it's unclear to me how we can solve the general case, or even prove that the constructions are optimal. Any insight is greatly appreciated :)

Edit: after some reflection, I have a few observations for the first case, i.e. when each cell has at most two adjacent cells. The optimal configuration to $m\times n$ always seems to be a filled-in border with the optimal solution to $(m-4)\times(n-4)$ nested inside. Here is an example with $9\times 20$ having a $5\times 16$ nested inside:

Also, for a $4\times n$ board the pattern seems to be:


Can you state your solution for "$ 4 \times n$, where each cell has at most two adjacent black cells"?

i'm confused as to how you proved it for small cases... for 3x3, the answer to the first question is 6, and for the second it is 8. your construction is also suboptimal for eg 5x7.

Let me rephrase. The main question is what is the optimal case when each square has at most two adjacent black squares. The constructions given are my attempts to solve the problem. I don’t have a construction for the other question yet.

How did you get the pictures? I am trying to write up a readable solution and the pictures you have are very nice.

For both conditions, I can prove that the corners must be colored in, but not much else.

@Nic See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271584

For $5 \times 100$, the maximum for the original question is indeed $302$.  But for the related question where only the black cells must have at most two black neighbors, the maximum (obtained via integer linear programming) is instead $334$:

Here are the details for both formulations.  For each cell $(i,j)$, let $N_{ij}$ be the set of neighboring cells, and let binary decision variable $x_{ij}$ indicate whether cell $(i,j)$ is black.  The objective is to maximize $\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij}$.  For the first problem, the constraints are
\begin{align}
\sum_{(u,v)\in N_{ij}} x_{uv} &\le 2 &&\text{for all $i,j$} \tag1\label1
\end{align}
For the second problem, the constraints are
\begin{align}
x_{ij} = 1 \implies \sum_{(u,v)\in N_{ij}} x_{uv} &\le 2 &&\text{for all $i,j$} \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Constraint \eqref{2} can be linearized via big-M constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_{(u,v)\in N_{ij}} x_{uv} - 2 &\le (|N_{ij}|-2)(1-x_{ij}) &&\text{for all $i,j$} \tag3\label3
\end{align}

That's so cool! Can this formulation then be used to prove the formulas derived by @Nolord?

+1: A nice application of MILP!

This answer conjecture the maximal amount of black squares if each cell has at most two adjacent black cells.
Indeed it seems that the optimal solution for some large $m\times n$ correspond to to the optimal $(m-4) \times (n-4)$ in the middle of the $m\times n$ grid, with the border colored, we call a ring.
(this has been proven false by the counter example $8\times17$ where we can draw $2$ sets of loops containing another loop).
This means the the $1\times n$, $2\times n$, $3\times n$ and $4\times n$ cases are the base cases, and all other configurations follow from adding rings to them.
The $1\times n$ and $3\times n$ both have a trivial coloring ($3\times n$ is shown below)

Whereas the $2\times n$ and $4\times n$ have a repeating pattern, shown below for increasing $n$

The $4\times n$ was inspired by OP's proposition.
These seems optimal and straightforward. We denote $F(m, n)$ the number of black squares in a $\boldsymbol{(m+1)}\times n$ grid (the choice of the $(m+1)$ will appear obvious later). By a straightforward counting

$F(0, n) = n$
$F(1, n) = 2(n - \left\lfloor \frac{n}{3}\right\rfloor)$
$F(2, n) = 2n + \delta_{n-1}$
$F(3, n) = 2(n + 1 + \left\lfloor \frac{n+1}{5}\right\rfloor)$

These are the base cases of the formula (below) that translates what we described earlier (valid for $m < n$)
\begin{align}
F(m, n) - \underbrace{F\left(m \bmod 4, n - 4\left\lfloor \frac{m}{4}\right\rfloor\right)}_{\text{the inner coloring}}
&= \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor m/4 \rfloor}}_{\substack{\text{a sum over } \\ \text{each ring}}} \underbrace{2(m+1-4(k-1)) + 2(n-2-4(k-1))}_{\text{the number of squares in each ring}} \\
&= 2\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor m/4 \rfloor} (m+n-1-8(k-1)) \\
&= 2\left\lfloor \frac{m}{4}\right\rfloor (m+n-1) - 8 \left\lfloor \frac{m}{4}\right\rfloor \left(\left\lfloor \frac{m}{4}\right\rfloor-1\right) \\
&= 2\left\lfloor \frac{m}{4}\right\rfloor \left(m+n-1 - 4 \left\lfloor \frac{m}{4}\right\rfloor + 4\right) \\
&= 2\left\lfloor \frac{m}{4}\right\rfloor \left(m \bmod 4 +n+3\right)
\end{align}
Hence the formula
$$
F(m, n) = F\left(m \bmod 4, n - 4\left\lfloor \frac{m}{4}\right\rfloor\right) + 2\left\lfloor \frac{m}{4}\right\rfloor \left(m \bmod 4 +n+3\right).
$$
We verify the result for the $5\times 100$ case
$$
F(4, 100) = F(0, 100 - 4) + 2(0 + 100 + 3) = 96 +206 = 302,
$$
as expected.
I would appreciate if anyone have a counter-example. But if this formula happens to be correct, the proof will probably require to be done on all separate cases.

$F(2,n)=2n$ if and only if $n>1$.

I found a counterexample! In an $8\times 17$ board, the maximum number is $80$. The construction features two $8\times8$ loops with $4\times 4$ loops inside them. Your formula gives $F(7,17)=F(3,13)+2(3+17+3)=32+46=78$.

Indeed! So the problem seems much harder then..

I confirm that $80$ is optimal for $8 \times 17$.  For the first problem, it seems that the linear programming relaxation yields the correct optimal value, and the resulting optimal dual solution provides a short certificate of optimality.

Progress on the $4\times n$ case, using a different approach:
For a $4\times21$ board, we colour some of its cells red as such

The key property of this colouring is that each cell is adjacent to exactly one red cell. For each red cell, there are at most $2$ adjacent black cells. Since there are $26$ red cells, we conclude there are at most $26\cdot2=52$ black cells. The construction exemplifying this is:


We can use this method to find the largest number of black cells for any $4\times n$ board. For the sake of completeness, I will prove all cases. Common remarks for all cases $5k+r$ are that we colour the left $4\times 5k$ part of the board using $k$ copies of

and colour the remaining $4\times r$ part of the board in a suitable way

$n=5k$:

Each cell is adjacent to exactly one red cell, except the two blue cells. Hence, there are at most $k\cdot 6\cdot 2 + 2=12k+2$ black cells. Here is the construction with $k-1$ copies of $4\times 4$ loops and one $4\times 5$ loop.


$n=5k+1$:

Here each cell is adjacent to exactly one red cell, except the four blue cells. Hence, there are at most $k\cdot 6\cdot 2 + 4=12k+4$ black cells. A construction with $k$ copies of $4\times4$ loops and a filled-out last column:


$n=5k+2$:

Each cell is adjacent to exactly one red cell, except for the two blue cells. Hence, there are at most $(k\cdot 6+2)\cdot 2 + 2=12k+6$
black cells. A construction, similar to the previous one, just adds two more black cells in the right corners.


$n=5k+3$:

Each cell is adjacent to exactly one red cell, except for the four blue cells. Hence, there are at most $(k\cdot 6+2)\cdot 2 + 4=12k+8$ black cells. The suitable construction just adds two black cells to the previous one:


$n=5k+4$:

Each cell is adjacent to exactly one red cell, except the eight blue cells. Hence, there are at most $(k\cdot 6+1)\cdot 2 + 8=12k+12$
black cells. A construction with $k+1$ loops of size $4\times 4$:


We conclude that the largest number of black cells for a $4\times n$ board is $2(n+1+\lfloor\frac{n+1}{5}\rfloor)$, just as @Nolord conjectured.

I have proven the case for $m\ge n$, $m$ odd. As common remarks, we colour the even rows of the board red. Let $c_i$ be the number of black cells adjacent to $i$ red cells. Notice that $c_0=c_3=c_4=0$. Let $R$ be the set of red pairs $(i,j)$ of indices. Denote by $f(i,j)$ the number of adjacent black cells to cell $(i,j$). Our condition is equivalent to $f(i,j)\le2$ for all $i,j$.


If $m=4k+1$,
$$c_1+2c_2=\sum_{(i,j)\in R}f(i,j)\le 2|R|=4kn.$$
On the other hand, $c_1\le 4k+2n$. Summing these two inequalities and dividing by two yields $c_1+c_2\le 2kn + 2k + n$. This construction proves that this really is the maximum:

We can also prove that this construction is unique. Consider when equality holds for $c_1+c_2 = 2kn + 2k + n$. Then both inequalities become equalities. $c_1+2c_2=4kn$ implies that every red cell has exactly two adjacent black cells. $c_1= 4k+2n$ implies that every cell adjacent to exactly one red cell is black. Using these two conditions we can inductively prove:




If $m=4k+3$,
$$c_1+2c_2=\sum_{(i,j)\in R}f(i,j)\le 2|R|=4kn+2n.$$
On the other hand, $c_1\le 4k+2n+2$. Summing these two inequalities and dividing by two gives $c_1+c_2\le 2kn + 2k + 2n + 1$. Assume for the sake of contradiction that $c_1+c_2=2kn+2k+2n+1$. Then, in the same way as in the $4k+1$ case, both inequalities become equalities. Reasoning in a similar way (by taking into account that each red cell has exactly two adjacent black cells, and each cell adjacent to exactly one red cell is black,) we get the following configuration:

But this configuration only has $2kn + 2k + 2n$ black squares, so we arrive at a contradiction. Hence we have shown that $c_1+c_2\le 2kn + 2k + 2n$ and since we found a suitable construction, we are done!
It can also be seen that this solution is not unique, and the optimal solution need not have its outer edges black. Here are two examples for $11\times 23$:

